# Laravel voyager - requirements could not be resolve

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I used `laravel 5.4` for my project and install [voyager admin package](https://voyager.readme.io/v1.1/docs/installation)
It shows an errors. How can I fix these errors?

`PHP version - PHP 5.6.31`

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - tcg/voyager v1.1.0 requires intervention/image ^2.4 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.4.0, 2.4.1].
    - tcg/voyager v1.1.1 requires intervention/image ^2.4 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.4.0, 2.4.1].
    - intervention/image 2.4.1 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.4.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for tcg/voyager ^1.1 -> satisfiable by tcg/voyager[v1.1.0, v1.1.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.6\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: what os is this project currently on? mac? windows? linux? ubuntu? other?

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to include the OS. it's Windows 10

Comment: You need to enable/install the `fileinfo` extension

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have **php_fileinfo.dll** in **php.ini** file then check in x**ampp/php/ext** folder if you have php_fileinfo.dll file in that folder. If you have dll file then add

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

this line in php.ini file. If you don't have dll file in folder than **download it** from internet according to your PHP version, and **put it in xampp/php/ext** folder and add above line php.ini. After that restart xampp.

[Download link for dll file](http://www.topdll.com/download/php_fileinfo.dll?q=d118d63936aa11ad88100d50af564c55)

Comment: in my case also need add these line without semicolumns to php.ini --> ;extension=pcre.so
also ;extension=spl.so

Answer (score 0):

[To install/activate the extension on windows, the following can be done](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php):

Open the mentioned ini file (`C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.6\php.ini`

Then search for `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` and make sure it is commented out.

After that close and reopen your commandline, then the install should succeed.

Comment: There is no `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`  found under the  `(C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.6\php.ini` file

Comment: i mean no  such word found

Comment: could you share the contents of the `php.ini` file? do be sure there is no sensitive information in there first though.

Comment: here [click this link](https://gist.github.com/worstn8mare/b87d9ad05744d758327e9c2c12c2b9c3)

Comment: that url returns a 404